# How to assign MAX value from mySQL query into PHP variable?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to store the MAX value of the following mySQL query :

```
$maxTF = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(tf) AS maxTF FROM my_database")or die(mysql_error());

echo $maxTF;
```

But i didn't get the value. Could someone tell how to make it works ? thanks in advance.

Comment: I think mysqli, which version of php you are using? use --> http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: I'm using PHP 5.6.27

Comment: did you execute the query?

Comment: This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0 from here --> http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: @affaz yes, the output is Resource id #84. what does it mean ?

Comment: @Kumar so i have to change my PHP version to 7.0.0 ?

Comment: pls post the fetch row code too..you have to use $row['MAX(tf)'];

Comment: @brown26 Its depend upon you, But you should follow documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$maxTF` isn't the value being selected, it's the *result of the query*.  Which is an object itself from which you can fetch records and values.  In this case exactly one record will be returned by this query, and that record will contain exactly one value.

Looking at [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) shows some examples you can use.  (When doing so, do also pay attention to that red box at the top of the page.  You're using a data connection library that's no longer supported.)  Something like this:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($maxTF);
echo $row['maxTF'];
```